# Android GridView item touched listener

Tags: android, android-gridview, touch-event, onkeydown

I can't find a solution for my problem. I have a gridview with layouts. The layouts contains an imageview and a textview. What I need is to animate the imageview when I touch an item. How can I detect the on item keydown event in the gridview?

Here is my adapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<SingleButton> buttons;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public GridViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.buttons = new ArrayList<SingleButton>();

        Resources res = mainActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources();
        String[] temp = res.getStringArray(R.array.buttons);
        int[] buttonImages = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,
                R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5,
                R.drawable.pic6, R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8,
                R.drawable.pic9 };

        for (int count = 0; count < 9; ++count) {
            this.buttons
                    .add(new SingleButton(buttonImages[count], temp[count]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.buttons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.buttons.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mainActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_button, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.buttonImage.setImageResource(buttons.get(position).image);
        holder.buttonText.setText(buttons.get(position).buttonText);

        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView buttonImage;
        TextView buttonText;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            this.buttonImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewButton);
            this.buttonText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewButton);
        }
    }

    class SingleButton {
        int image;
        String buttonText;

        SingleButton(int image, String buttonText) {
            this.image = image;
            this.buttonText = buttonText;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your adapter code. You need to change into getView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `View.OnTouchListener` to the parent view, in which your image is. Here parent view is your grid row.

It can be done via using `setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener)`. Below is code, you need to replace ViewHolder class with below code.

```
class ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ImageView buttonImage;
    TextView buttonText;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        this.buttonImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewButton);
        this.buttonText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewButton);
        v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
            // Here you can put animation for your image view
            // this.buttonImage is the target image view.
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked but onItemClick() is not called. I need to know which item has been clicked.

Comment: Share your code where you called this adapter and used onItemClick().

Answer (score 0):

you can find the item that has been clicked with findChildViewUnder(x,y) :

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    View child = findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null) {
        yourInterfaceClickListener.click(getChildAdapterPosition(child));
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
}
```